# length.java:15: error: cannot find symbol, length.java:16: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class length
{
public static void main(String[]args){
double ft=0;
String ftS;

ftS=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Meter");
ft=Double.parseDouble(ftS);
String output;
double in=ft*12;
double cm=in*2.54;
double mm=cm*10;
output = String.format("feet is %.2f",ft)+Sring.format("\nfeet to in:%.2f",in)+String.format("\nfeet to cm:%.2f",cm)+String.format("\nfeet to mm:%.2f",mm);
JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, output);
}
}
```

the error is :

```
length.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    output = String.format("feet is %.2f",ft)+Sring.format("\nfeet to in:%.2f",in)+String.format("\nfeet to cm:%.2f",cm)+String.format("\nfeet to mm:%.2f",mm);
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable Sring
  location: class length
length.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, output);
               ^
  symbol:   method ShowMessageDialog(<null>,String)
  location: class JOptionPane
2 errors
```

Comment: Indent your code for a better world.

Comment: Can we see more of your error message?

Comment: In future, please indent your code and put the error message in the *question* rather than just in the title. I suspect the full error message included the symbol which wasn't found, too...

Comment: Don't just dump the error message in without formatting it. Can you see that there's a preview box when you write a post? Make sure *when you're writing the post* that it looks good before you post it. Please read the help on editing, or you'll keep getting downvotes and your questions will be closed.

Comment: ****thanks!**** sorry for that one

Answer (score 4):

This is one problem:

```
JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(...)
```

There's now such method as `ShowMessageDialog`. It's `showMessageDialog` - Java is case-sensitive.

And as pointed out in comments, `Sring.format` should be `String.format` as well.

Don't just fix the problem though - take a step back and work out why you couldn't figure out either of these on your own. In an IDE, you'd probably have a red squiggle under the *exact* places which were wrong. Even if you weren't in an IDE, the error message should have told you the exact line and column containing the error.

Once you can see that there's an error at a specific problem, you should look at it carefully, bearing in mind that the compiler *will* be picky about names.

EDIT: Now that you've included the error messages, they do indeed point out the exact problems:

```
symbol:   variable Sring
symbol:   method ShowMessageDialog(<null>,String)
```

You should have looked at both of those and worked out what was wrong from there. I'm not saying this to tell you off - just to help you fix it yourself next time.

Comment: OK, lets see if Jason can beat you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. The first from line 15 is:

```
Sring.format
```

should be

```
String.format
```

Your other problem is from line 16 is:

```
JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog
```

should be

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
```

Look at your error message!

```
length.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    output = String.format("feet is %.2f",ft)+Sring.format("\nfeet to in:%.2f",in)+String.format("\nfeet to cm:%.2f",cm)+String.format("\nfeet to mm:%.2f",mm);
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable Sring
  location: class length
length.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, output);
               ^
  symbol:   method ShowMessageDialog(<null>,String)
  location: class JOptionPane
2 errors
```

Both of them are telling you *exactly* what to look at! They are telling you `Sring` is not a valid symbol and `ShowMessageDialog` is not a valid symbol. You probably could have very quickly figured out the first one on your own, and the second one as well if you remember that the convention in Java is to use lower-case for the first letter of a method name. And in the worst case you can [Google "`JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog`"](https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog) and get taken to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) and see that the method is *actually* `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`.